# How to find repeated values in Array List?

Tags: arrays, perl, search

In array List

```
my @array = ('val1','val2','val3','val4','val1');
```

I would like to get output like below

```
Output:
No of repetition of Val1 = 2 times
```

Please help me to get this output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Perl, `{…}` creates a *hash reference*, not an array – those are initialized using a list `(…)`. You should consider to `use strict; use warnings;` as a safety net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash:

```
my @array = ('val1','val2','val3','val4','val1');    
my %seen;
my $element;
foreach $element (@array){
    $seen{$element}++
}

foreach my $val (keys %seen){
    print "No of repetition of $val = $seen{$val} times\n" if ($seen{$val} > 1);
}
```

Prints:

```
No of repetition of val1 = 2 times
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my @array = ('val1','val2','val3','val4','val1');

my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for @array;

print "No of repetition of $_ = $seen{$_} times\n"
  for grep $seen{$_} >1, sort keys %seen;
```